# How to stretch images to fill a figure tag

Tags: html, css

I am building a grid of images and I have a list of figure tags with one image inside each one.
Images are different in size so if I set

```
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

they don't look the same.

How can I make all images to fit the figure to be all the same size? it is OK for me to stretch the images that does not fit perfectly.

thanks

Comment: Do u want stretch the image or cover the image?

Comment: I would like to stretch it

Answer (score 1):

Use `objectfit` on `img` tag with `contain` or `cover` properties

```
figure img {
    object-fit: contain;//contain the image you can use cover to fill the div with image
    width: 200px;//desire width
    height: 200px;//desire height
}
```

Comment: needs to be responsive, I can't specify a H and W.

Comment: fit the figure to be all the same size,,,,, figure have some `height` and `width` alright ?

Comment: Set width to `100%` then, But you need to give some height so that all image were look alike

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the styles in css.. but i think this is not a correct rule to stretch the image.. we can use background image in css instead of stretch..

**css**

```
figure img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```